# How do I prevent vim from 'smart' auto alignment that causes spaces to be inserted after tabs?

Tags: vim

For instance if I attempt to split up

```
\t\tvery.long.line
```

to

```
\t\tvery.long
\t\t\t.line
```

Sometimes leading spaces are inserted (presumably for alignment) so it looks like:

```
\t\tvery.long
\t\t\t   .line
```

I'd prefer the leading spaces not to be present.  How do I disable this?

I thought it might be a plugin, but I don't appear to have any that'd cause this behaviour.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you open vim without plugins/vimrc with `vimr -u NONE filename` ?  A possible fix would be to use the auto command: `autocmd InsertLeave * silent! %s/\(^\t\+\) \+/\1/` to remove leading spaces when preceded by tabs

Comment: @Segio So..this is interesting.  `vim -u NONE file` doesn't have that behaviour.  Neither does `vim -u NONE file` + `:source ~/.vimrc`.  But if I open vim directly, I can reproduce it.  `vim --noplugins file` also reproduces the issue.

PS: I assume `vimr` is a typo?  I can't find a command like that